# Why can't I get overloaded strings?

Tags: haskell

This is the code I have in my file `Temp.hs` :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Temp where

import Data.String

string1 = "Darth Vader"
string2 = "Obi-Wan Kenobi"
```

The problem is that I want Overloaded Strings. From what I understand, overloaded strings are polymorphic, belonging to the typeclass `IsString`. So when load the above file in GHC and do

`:t string1`,

I should get

`string1 :: Data.String.IsString a => a`

But what I get is:

`string1 :: String`

Help!

Comment: Monomorphism restriction? Try `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriciton #-}`

Comment: Could also just add the desired type explicitly.  Always use explicit type signatures on your top level declarations!

Comment: @user2407038 Yes, that solved it. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson What do you mean by 'add the desired type explicitly'? I am sorry but I did not get it.

Comment: @RedJohn e.g. add `string1 :: IsString a => a` (or `string1 :: Text` or whatever) to your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer in based on [user2407038](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2407038/user2407038)'s comment.
It turns out that adding `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriciton #-}` to the code solves the problem. But I wouldn't recommend it. Read [Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).

But as it turns out, you don't have to do it. GHC does its Monomorphism thing and sets the type of `string1` to `String`, but only because it thought that you didn't want it to be anything else. But the `OverloadedStrings` extension is still in effect! You'll notice that if you do something like

`string1 = "Darth Vader"::ByteString`

GHC will be more that happy to make your `string1` variable a `ByteString`.

One more thing I noticed in Haskell's Monomorphism Restriction Wiki page, is:

> The restriction is turned on by default in compiled modules, and
>   turned off by default at the GHCi prompt (since GHC 7.8.1).